# Execute code in React children after parent componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, axios, lifecycle

I'm using axios for web requests and have created an interceptor for it to show a toaster for all error messages.

I'm using react-intl for translations and the generic error message present in the interceptor is translated, so I'm tying the interceptor to my application's lifecycle:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {

    // addToastInterceptor calls back for a message that can be evaluated dynamically
    // otherwise it uses axios.interceptors.response.use(...)
    this.interceptor = addToastInterceptor((e) =>
      this.props.intl.formatMessage({
        id: 'applicationForm.basic.errorMessage'
      }, {
        technicalMessage: e.message
      }));
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    // the interceptor handle is removed when the component unmounts
    removeToastInterceptor(this.interceptor);
  }

  render() {
    // any number of child component in any depth
  }
}

// The intl provider must exist in a wrapper component
export default injectIntl(Main);
```

This way while the `Main` component is mounted, any axios call that receives an error response will trigger a toast message.

My problem is the following. If I try to make a call with axios before `Main.componentDidMount` is called the message will not show up.

If I make a call in a descendant component's `componentDidMount`, it will not show the message:

```
// This component dispatches a redux call that uses axios.get internally
class SomeChild extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    // this is 
    this.props.getCountriesAction();
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  countries: state.boarding.countries,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
  getCountriesAction: getCountries,
}, dispatch);

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(SomeChild);
```

One workaround would be to use the constructor (or componentWillMoount) of Main to register the interceptor, but this would not hold up with async rendering because these methods are not guaranteed to run only once.

Can I somehow change the order of the 2 `componentDidMount` calls or use any other lifecycle methods for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what `addToastInterceptor` does. I think it is fine to call it inside the `constructor`.
In case some work really needs to be done inside `componentDidMount` before childrens` lifecycle methods you can use a flag to delay children rendering till everything is ready:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  state = {isReady: false}

  componentDidMount () {

    // addToastInterceptor calls back for a message that can be evaluated dynamically
    // otherwise it uses axios.interceptors.response.use(...)
    this.interceptor = addToastInterceptor((e) =>
      this.props.intl.formatMessage({
        id: 'applicationForm.basic.errorMessage'
      }, {
        technicalMessage: e.message
      }));

    this.setState({isReady: true});
  }

  render {
    if (!this.state.isReady) return null;
    ...
  }
}
```

If the work inside `componentDidMount` takes a long time and you want to have something rendered you can pass `isReady` flag to children and move their logic from `componentDidMount` to `componentDidUpdate`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.isReady && this.props.isReady !== prevProps.isReady) {
    /* child's logic from componentDidMount */
  }
}
```

Comment: I really don't want explicit parameters to be passed around especially since the child is not necessarily a direct child but a descendant. I could use context but that would be a little heavy for this. I would gladly use the ctor but that is not guaranteed to only run once and it could potentially register the same interceptor many times.

Comment: Then you should use only the first part of the solution and `return null` or some busy indicator instead of children on the first render